# Is it possible to follow the Michael Hartl tutorial on windows 8 64 bit?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, windows, serverside-javascript

WARNING! I am a complete newb to programming...

**problem:**
ok so I've searched and seen ever solution I could find on getting ruby on rails to work properly on my machine with windows 8 64 bit with no success. as of today what is the best version of ruby and rails that will work on a PC. is there a tutorial that is as highly recommended as the Michael Hartl tutorial that uses a version that is stable on my operating system?

**my plan b**
also is there another route I can take for server side? I am most comfortable with javascript so I was thinking of learning node.js instead. What are the pro's and cons of using node.js over ruby on rails.

**what im trying to build**
I have built a very simple music blog. I built a form for users to make and submit there own blog posts. update a blog post template html file i made with the user input from the form using js and jquery. the part I don't understand is generating a new page each time a form is submitted. right now when i fill out the form it just changes the template file without creating a new page.

thanks for any suggestions and sorry if this is hella newbish

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to familiarize yourself with the Stack Overflow help file, which will help you understand what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site. This site is intended to help you obtain answers to *specific programming questions*, as opposed to providing tutorial, design or code review assistance.

Comment: Also, what makes you think that there's some problem with Win8 and Rails? Don't assume there's some compatibility issue when it could very well be that as a newbie, you just don't know how to interpret what you're seeing.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I'm not simply assuming. I've seen that a lot of other people have had the same problem and I have been able to successfully install and build a simple app in rails on cloud9. i thought my question was a specific programming question.